# Where and how to use locationServicesEnabled: true,locationServicesAuthorized: true, capabilities with web driver?

Tags: ios, appium

Where and how to use  locationServicesEnabled: true,locationServicesAuthorized: true, capabilities with web driver?

What is the use setting this capabilities ?

I am getting a default location pop up while doing ios mobile automation testing in simulator.Can this help me to handle this pop ups?

Answer (score 0):

The desired capability you want to use to automatically dismiss popovers, such as the location one, is `'autoAcceptAlerts': True`

This will dismiss all alerts automatically by pressing the "default" button, so long as Instruments is able to connect to the App.

If the UIAlert is the first thing to display, Instruments will complain that the target application is not "foreground".

Comment: This is not working for me.Still the default location pop up is being displayed and I have to close this manually :(

Comment: Any other way to handle this through our scripts

Comment: Is the alert the first thing that happens when the app is launched?

Comment: yes ... the very first thing ...unless we click on that pop up we are not able to proceed

Comment: Yeah that's a bug with Appium. I don't believe there's an easy way to get around it. You may be able to do some javascript magic.

Comment: Do javascripts work the same way with emulators as they do for web applications?Can you please help me with the code for javascript

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Look into iOS's uiautomation tutorials. The function is onAlert